# TFS 2017 MSBuild 15 task Error:MSB4184 - Illegal characters in path

Tags: msbuild

I'm converting a TFS 2013 XAML build to TFS 2017 task build.  I get this error when building a project file:

> 2019-06-20T17:23:37.0504912Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue
>   type=Error;sourcepath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Fakes\Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.targets;linenumber=13;columnnumber=5;code=MSB4184;]The
>   expression
>   "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(C:\Agent_work\1\s\Code\DatabaseProjects\Audit\,
>   obj\Auto\Any CPU|Default\Fakes)" cannot be evaluated. Illegal
>   characters in path.

I've looked everywhere for what's happening and nothing is jumping out at me.

Answer (score 0):

My initial problem was focusing on the comma in the IO.Path.Combine rather than the pipe char later on.  Once I realized it was the dang pipe I figured it out ASAP.

In TFS 2013 XAML builds the Configurations line has the platform and configuration **separated by the pipe char**.
However in TFS 2017 task builds there are **two lines**.  *One for Platform* and *another for Configuration*.  Once I put Any CPU as the platform and Default as the Configuration things started working much better.

[image]